Flutter web SSE listener
I'm encountering an issue when trying to establish a connection with an SSE (Server-Sent Events) API endpoint on Flutter Web. The code works correctly on iOS and Android platforms, but on Flutter Web, it gets stuck at await when sending the request and never reaches the second log (x2).
Here’s my code:
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
...

final request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse('${Constants.api}bets/listen/$betId'));
request.headers.addAll(Constants.header(token: _userRepository.user.token));
request.headers['Accept'] = 'text/event-stream';

log('x1');
final response = await http.Client().send(request);
log('x2 ${response.statusCode}');

What I’ve observed:
-The code gets stuck at the await line and never reaches the second log.
-There is no timeout, and the request does not seem to resolve.
-The same code works on iOS and Android but not on Flutter Web.
What I’ve tried:
-Verified that the issue only occurs in the web environment and not on mobile platforms.
-Look for other SSE implementation using http package (with no luck)
Environment:
Flutter version: 3.24.3
Web platform

It might be related to buffering. When the response is smaller than the buffer size, it waits indefinitely for more content. Try bigger or more events.
I encountered something similar on the dart server side and was able to disable buffering with the "shelf.io.buffer_output": false flag.
